# Joining tables in Crystal on truncated field

Tags: sql, join, crystal-reports, truncate

I'm trying to join a table with user information in it to an existing Crystal report. I would like to create join based on the first 7 characters in one field in my first table matching a unique ID in my second table.

I'm pretty sure the equivalent SQL would just be

```
JOIN db.table2 on left(db.table1.userid, 7) = db.table2.userid
```

But I'm not sure how to translate this to what goes on in Crystal's GUI (or if it is even possible to do in Crystal). I would do it in Command, but the existing report is already using fields from a whole bunch of different tables linked through Crystal's own way of doing things and it would take forever to remap them all if I convert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do a join like that from the Database Expert but you could put that logic into the Record Selection Formula with `left({table1.userid},7) = {table2.userid}`.

It should be noted, though, that this is pretty hacky and CR generally doesn't like when you add two conventionally unjoined tables to a report like that. Just a quick local test tells me that doing it this way does not actually translate into a well-formed WHERE-clause, but that CR enforces the "join" locally. In other words, your mileage may vary.

Comment: I ended up joining the tables on two other fields (first name and last name) instead, should be ok because it's unlikely that we'll ever have two employees with exactly the same first and last. I will keep your answer for future reference though, I'm sure it will come in handy one day. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Joe Glad to hear it worked out. Keep in mind that this is really a database design issue and your primary/foreign keys should be in agreement.